# FadeIN FadeOUT page transition javascript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click any of my links to take me to a new HTML page, the javascript routes me to the same HTML page and not each links individual href.

Heres my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('display', 'none');
  $('body').fadeIn(1000);
  $('.link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = $('.link a').attr("href");
    $('body').fadeOut(1000, newpage);
  });
  function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="music" class="link"><a href="pages/music/index.html">Music</a></div>
<div id="exhibition" class="link"><a href="pages/exhibition/index.html">Exhibition</a></div>
<div id="contact" class="link"><a href="pages/contact/index.html">Contact</a></div>
<div id="about" class="link"><a href="pages/about/index.html">About</a></div>
```

My aim is to have the Page FadeIN on load and FadeOUT when a link has been clicked, I am getting my desired effect but im just not sure what this issue with the links is -  Anyone know?

Comment: can you paste your html code

Comment: Ive added it now

Comment: I feel like part of the issue may be that you are preventing the default on the click of the div, not the actual `<a>` clicked.  I haven't tested this yet though.  Also as a side note, `newLocation = $('.link a').attr("href");` is performing a global lookup for the link, contrary to just using the div that was just clicked for a contextual lookup.

Comment: it's working fine in our system, what is problem was?

Comment: Its still happening for me, do you think maybe it could be some kind of cache issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Taplar says, when you fetch the location from the link's `href`, you're not getting the right one. You're just fetch the first link in the document and looking at its `href` attribute.

You can easily fix this by replacing this (which looks for all anchor elements in the document that have an ancestor with the `link` class and then returns the first one it finds):

```
newLocation = $('.link a').attr('href');
```

with this (which finds all anchor elements as a child of whatever element has the click handler registered that was clicked):

```
newLocation = $(event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href');
```

The other thing you're doing that is tricky, but doesn't necessarily break anything, is relying on `newLocation` being correctly shared between the `click` handler and the `newpage` function. I would suggest instead that you explicitly pass a parameter to newpage so that it is more reusable and you can be sure where the value is coming from.

You can see this working below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('display', 'none');
  $('body').fadeIn(1000);
  $('.link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = $(event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href');
    // Pass anonymous function to fadeOut that calls newpage with newLocation
    $('body').fadeOut(1000, function () { newpage(newLocation); });
  });
  // newpage now accepts a parameter and uses it
  function newpage(location) {
    // Print to console so you can see what URL is getting used
    // You'll always get 404 using StackOverflow's UI since they don't have the relevant pages
    console.log(location);
    window.location = location;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="music" class="link"><a href="pages/music/index.html">Music</a></div>
<div id="exhibition" class="link"><a href="pages/exhibition/index.html">Exhibition</a></div>
<div id="contact" class="link"><a href="pages/contact/index.html">Contact</a></div>
<div id="about" class="link"><a href="pages/about/index.html">About</a></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Please "accept" the answer if you're happy with it :)